# When I add the same virtual subnet ID to two virtual network adapters they can't ping each other

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, cloud-computing

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 with Hyper-v role installed.

It is nested virtualization with VMware Workstation

VM1 on host 1

VM2 on host 1

Added VSID to both VM network adapters: 4666

Windows firewall on both VMs allows ping

When the VM VSID is set to 0 they can ping each other.

When the VM VSID is set to another number they cannot reach each other.

The Hyper-v Virtual Switch is of type external

It also has multiple ManagementOS Virtual adapters attached to it with different VLAN numbers.

I think NVGRE is already enabled in the switch in R2, correct?

The goal is to get these two VMs talking to each other via NVGRE

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you only configured VSID for VMs , it won't work for network virtualization .
There are also something other need to configure , such as PA . PA is needed during NVGRE encapsulation .
For details , please check the following article for network virtualization:
[Network Virtualization](http://techgenix.com/deep-dive-hyper-v-network-virtualization-part1/)